# How to find the type of an object in a set?

Tags: python

How do I find the type of an object that is in a set with using one line code?

```
setup = {(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)}

>>> type(setup.____)

<class 'int'>
```

Comment: The type of *which* object? The type of all the objects in your `set` is `tuple`, not `int`. What if there are different types? Why does it have to be on one line?

Comment: `[type(s[0]) for s in setup][0]` if you don't mind wasting a little memory.

Comment: @Shiva save some memory *and time* using `next`: `type(next(s[0] for s in setup))`.

Comment: Just  a guess, but are you trying to see if all of your data is homogeneous? This seems a bit like an XY problem.

Comment: Sets can hold many objects and they can all be different types—so as it stands your question make little sense. Please [edit] it and make it so folks don't have to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

```
type(setup) # set
type(next(iter(setup))) #tuple
type(next(iter(setup))[0]) #int
```

maybe? its really not clear what your question is... just cause one element of a set is a tuple does not mean all elements in the set are tuples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the type of each element in the tuple you can use list comprehension like:

```
[type(x) for elem in setup for x in elem]
```

output:

```
[<type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>]
```

or if you want to group them you can use:

```
[[type(x) for x in elem] for elem in setup]
```

to get the following output:

```
[[<type 'int'>, <type 'int'>], [<type 'int'>, <type 'int'>], [<type 'int'>, <type 'int'>]]
```